# Python pandas add multiple columns to dataframe with map

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks as follows.

```
player  count1  count2  text
A       1       1       X   
A       2       1       Y   
A       3       1       Z   
A       4       2       D   
A       5       2       E   
B       1       1       F   
B       2       2       G   
B       3       2       H   
B       4       2       J
```

Column `player` contains names, `count1` is a cumulative sum, column `count2` contains other counts, and column `text` contains some text.

I now want to create 2 new columns that contain the values of `count1` and `text` where the column `count2` first contains the value `2`.

Hence, the result should look like this:

```
player  count1  count2  text    new new2
A       1       1       X       4   D
A       2       1       Y       4   D
A       3       1       Z       4   D
A       4       2       D       4   D
A       5       2       E       4   D
B       1       1       F       2   G
B       2       2       G       2   G
B       3       2       H       2   G
B       4       2       J       2   G
```

I already asked a similar question, but where only, one new column should be added [here][1].

The answer was to use `map` by `Series`.

```
s = df[df['count2'] == 2].drop_duplicates(['player']).set_index('player')['count1']
df['new'] = df['player'].map(s)
```

However, when I try to apply this approach to two columns, it does not work.

I try it like this:

```
s = df[df['count2'] == 2].drop_duplicates(['player']).set_index('player')[['count1', 'text']]
df[['new', 'new2']] = df['player'].map(s)
```

This yields the following error:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Please note that the link to your other question is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter on count2 == 2, drop duplicates by player, then merge the result back to your original DF on player, eg:

```
new = df.merge(
    df.loc[df.count2 == 2, ['player', 'count1', 'text']]
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['player']), 
    on='player'
)
```

Which gives you:

```
  player  count1_x  count2 text_x  count1_y text_y
0      A         1       1      X         4      D
1      A         2       1      Y         4      D
2      A         3       1      Z         4      D
3      A         4       2      D         4      D
4      A         5       2      E         4      D
5      B         1       1      F         2      G
6      B         2       2      G         2      G
7      B         3       2      H         2      G
8      B         4       2      J         2      G
```